# Search Items are not showing up during search in SearchBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to add Search Bar in Flutter. And I have achieved the state where I can type content in the search bar but during writing the query the List is not updating.

**I want to sort on basis of blogName** and below is the code

```
class AllBlogs extends StatefulWidget {
  AllBlogs({Key key}) : super(key: key);


  final Color _tabBackgroudColor = const Color(0xFF1A237E);

  @override
  AllBlogsState createState() {
    return new AllBlogsState();
  }
}

class AllBlogsState extends State<AllBlogs> {

  Widget appBarTitle = Text("Blog's List");
  Icon actionIcon = Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,);

  final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final TextEditingController _searchQuery = new TextEditingController();

  bool _IsSearching;
  String _searchText = "";



  _SearchListState() {
    _searchQuery.addListener(() {
      if (_searchQuery.text.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          _IsSearching = false;
          _searchText = "";
        });
      }
      else {
        setState(() {
          _IsSearching = true;
          _searchText = _searchQuery.text;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _IsSearching = false;

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: buildBar(context),

      body: new Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
    child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: allblogs.length,
    // Facing Issue Here
    itemBuilder: _IsSearching ? buildSearchList : blogslist
    ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Facing Issue Here

  Widget buildSearchList(BuildContext context, int index){
     if (_searchText.isEmpty){
      return blogslist(context, index);
    }
    else {
       List<String> _searchList = List();
       for (int i = 0; i < allblogs.length; i++) {
         String name = (allblogs[index].blogName);
         if (name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase())) {
           _searchList.add(name);
         }
       }

      // Now what can i return to show the tile whoes blogName I searched for

       );

     }




  }



  Widget buildBar(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: appBarTitle,
      backgroundColor: widget._tabBackgroudColor,
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(icon: actionIcon,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if (this.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                // ignore: new_with_non_type
                this.actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white,);
                this.appBarTitle = TextField(
                  controller: _searchQuery,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(

                      prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                      hintText: "Search...",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                  ),
                );
                _handleSearchStart();
              }
              else {
                _handleSearchEnd();
              }
            });
          },),
      ],
    );
  }


  void _handleSearchStart() {
    setState(() {

      _IsSearching = true;

    });
  }

  void _handleSearchEnd() {
    setState(() {
      // ignore: new_with_non_type
      this.actionIcon =  new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,);
      this.appBarTitle = new Text("Search Sample", style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),);
      _IsSearching = false;
      _searchQuery.clear();
    });
  }


}




Widget blogslist(BuildContext context, int index){

  return Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            child: new Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/icons/stackexchange.png")),

          ),
          title: Text(allblogs[index].blogName,
            ),
          subtitle: Text(allblogs[index].blogName),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0),
          isThreeLine: true,
          trailing: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
            child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.launch, color: Colors.blue, size: 20.0,),
                onPressed: (){}),
          ),
        ),


        Divider(),
      ],
    ),

  );
}
```

**All I want is to search the ListTile widget in the flutter based on the title**
You can also see the image which I uploaded that shows I achieved the situation in which I can type something in the search bar. Now I just need to compare the input text with the ListTile's title, and show the matched tiles. 
[image: Look The Image]

I have created a list in different class like----

```
class AllBlogs {
  final String id;
  final String blogName;
  final String blogurl;
  final String about;

  const AllBlogs(
      {@required this.id,
      @required this.blogName,
      @required this.blogurl,
      @required this.about});
}

List<AllBlogs> allblogs = [
  const AllBlogs(
    id: '1',
    blogName: 'KDnuggets',
    blogurl: "https://www.kdnuggets.com/?ref=cybrhome",
    about: "KDnuggets is one of the most popular data science blogs, with articles that cover Business Analytics, Statistics, and Machine Learning.",
  ),
```

and when I am trying to write below code then at place of allblogs.It's showing an error of 'a value of type List can't be assigned to a variable of type List class.

Comment: You now have two different classes called 'AllBlogs'! You have the `StatefulWidget` and the class holding `id`, `blogName` etc. Rename one of them.

Comment: I already renamed 'List<Blog> _displayList = allblogs' as 'List<AllBlog> _displayList = allblogs' but facing issue with 'allblogs' saying 'a value of type List can't be assigned to a variable of type List class'

Comment: What's the class name of your `StatefulWidget`?

Comment: If I change the 'class AllBlogs extends StatefulWidget' to 'class AllBlog extends StatefulWidget. The code show no error but when I search It always end up showing top one result no matter what query I type.

Comment: Yes, I said that code is showing no error but at the time of search it always end up showing first one.

Comment: Can you confirm that if you use the code in the answer verbatim that you see the filtering you expect?

Comment: May be that the issue of using more than one field. I am also using 'blogurl', 'about', 'url'. and you are using only one i.e. 'blogName'. I think there is issue in filtering code because sublist is building up in a fine way.

Comment: But not able to filter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174514/discussion-between-richard-heap-and-mr-stark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `List<Blog>` somewhere called `allblogs`. Each time the search text changes form a new sublist as follows:

```
List<Blog> sublist = allblogs.where((b) => b.name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase())).toList();
```

(if search text is empty then simply assign allblogs to sublist)

Now use `sublist` everywhere you currently use `allblogs` in your builds.

So, on every change to the search criterion, you filter the full list down to the sub list that matches and (as long as you do that in setState) the Widget tree redraws showing just the filtered list.

Here's a complete working example based on your snippet above:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: 'Blogs Test',
    home: new AllBlogs(),
  ));
}

class Blog {
  String blogName;

  Blog(this.blogName);
}

List<Blog> allblogs = [
  Blog('flutter'),
  Blog('dart'),
  Blog('java'),
  Blog('python'),
];

class AllBlogs extends StatefulWidget {
  AllBlogs({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final Color _tabBackgroundColor = const Color(0xFF1A237E);

  @override
  AllBlogsState createState() => AllBlogsState();
}

class AllBlogsState extends State<AllBlogs> {
  Widget appBarTitle = Text("Blog's List");
  Icon actionIcon = Icon(
    Icons.search,
    color: Colors.white,
  );

  final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final TextEditingController _searchQuery = new TextEditingController();

  List<Blog> _displayList = allblogs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _searchQuery.addListener(() {
      if (_searchQuery.text.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          _displayList = allblogs;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          String s = _searchQuery.text;
          _displayList = allblogs
              .where((b) => b.blogName.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase()))
              .toList();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: buildBar(context),
      body: new Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _displayList.length,
          itemBuilder: _blogBuilder,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _blogBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              child: new Image(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/icons/stackexchange.png")),
            ),
            title: Text(_displayList[index].blogName),
            subtitle: Text(_displayList[index].blogName),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0),
            isThreeLine: true,
            trailing: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.launch,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 20.0,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {}),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildBar(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: appBarTitle,
      backgroundColor: widget._tabBackgroundColor,
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: actionIcon,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if (this.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                this.actionIcon = new Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: Colors.white,
                );
                this.appBarTitle = TextField(
                  controller: _searchQuery,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                      hintText: "Search...",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                );
              } else {
                this.actionIcon = new Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.white,
                );
                this.appBarTitle = new Text(
                  "Search Sample",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                );
                _searchQuery.clear();
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Still facing an issue, Tell what more code you want?

Comment: Again the same state I am typing the text in the searchBar but it's not searching the title?

Comment: what's the better approach to use _SearchListState ?

Comment: try the above as a standalone example